# How to make Flink Job Dag in Serial Sequence instead of Parrallel

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am using Table/SQL API

Job operations:

1. Read from Kafka and lookup with SQL to enrich and then upsert SQL table.
2. After upserting the SQL table flows the same events to Kafka Sink.

But the upserting in MySQL and inserting in Kafka is happening parallelly but we want a serial order like below

The flow we want :
LOOKUP KAFKA AND SQL -> UPSERT SQL -> INSERT KAFKA

The flow we are getting :
LOOKUP KAFKA AND SQL -> UPSERT SQL// INSERT KAFKA (Parrallel)

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done in a straightforward way. Sinks are terminal nodes in the job graph.

You could, however, use the async i/o operator to do the upsert and arrange for it to only emit events downstream to the kafka sink after the upsert has been completed.

Or you could have a second job that ingests a CDC stream from SQL and inserts to kafka.